# How to get a specific value from URL in PHP

Tags: php

I have a URL:

```
market://details?id=com.balancehero.truebalance&referrer=utm_source%3Dapp%26utm_medium%3Dlink%26utm_term%3D%26utm_content%3D%26utm_campaign%3Dmgm%26campid%3D2FC42T27%26m%3D1%26trackingid%3D000146132647632302db63d958690001
```

How can I get this value from above URL `000146132647632302db63d958690001`

Can I use `preg_match` function or something else.

Comment: have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Use urldecode(). Its solve your problem.

Comment: `echo "<pre/>";print_r($_GET);` and now you can get any value through it (atleast you have knowledge about fetching data from array)

Comment: I am using $trackid = substr($head['3'],199,300);
       print_r($trackid);

Comment: But this seems to be not helpful to me as sometimes i get 00146132647632302db63d958690001 value instead of 000146132647632302db63d958690001 this one zero missing

Comment: use urlencode and urldecode

Comment: `parse_str( urldecode($url), $array );` Then your string is in  `$array['trackingid']`

Comment: $_GET['trackingid']; 1st need to use urldecode

Answer (score 3):

If you are receiving it as real URL than as simple as:

```
echo $_GET['trackingid'];
```

Else:

```
$queryArray = [];
$query = parse_url(
    urldecode("market://details?id=com.balancehero.truebalance&referrer=utm_source%3Dapp%26utm_medium%3Dlink%26utm_term%3D%26utm_content%3D%26utm_campaign%3Dmgm%26campid%3D2FC42T27%26m%3D1%26trackingid%3D000146132647632302db63d958690001"),
    PHP_URL_QUERY
);
parse_str($query, $queryArray);
echo $queryArray['trackingid'];
```

[Live example](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83e213159d705d53dfce49c6ebc406c851877436)

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expressions for that. Otherwise you cann access it direcly with $_GET

```
$url='market://details?id=com.balancehero.truebalance&referrer=utm_source%3Dapp%26utm_medium%3Dlink%26utm_term%3D%26utm_content%3D%26utm_campaign%3Dmgm%26campid%3D2FC42T27%26m%3D1%26trackingid%3D000146132647632302db63d958690001';

if(preg_match("/([^\?]*)\?trackingid%(d*)/",$url,$matches)){
  echo $matches[1];
} else {
  $_GET['trackingid']
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) One method is using `explode()`.

```
$test = "market://details?id=com.balancehero.truebalance&referrer=utm_source%3Dapp%26utm_medium%3Dlink%26utm_term%3D%26utm_content%3D%26utm_campaign%3Dmgm%26campid%3D2FC42T27%26m%3D1%26trackingid%3D000146132647632302db63d958690001";
    $url = explode("trackingid=",urldecode($test));
    echo $url[1];
```

**Working Demo : [Click Here](https://eval.in/558015)**

2) Another is you can use `preg_match()` you can achieve it.

3) If you are getting it in url then get it using **`$_GET['trackingid']`**.

4) Using `parse_str()`.

```
$url = urldecode("market://details?id=com.balancehero.truebalance&referrer=utm_source%3Dapp%26utm_medium%3Dlink%26utm_term%3D%26utm_content%3D%26utm_campaign%3Dmgm%26campid%3D2FC42T27%26m%3D1%26trackingid%3D000146132647632302db63d958690001");
parse_str($url, $tempArray);
echo $tempArray['trackingid'];
```